# Not enough permissions for sharesV2.CREATE despite having w_organization_social

Tags: linkedin-api, make.com

I'm trying to use the LinkedIn API via Make/Integromat to automate the sharing of posts made on one of my brand pages across my other brand pages.

The API call is consistently failing with a permission error, even though I have an authorised connection with what I understand to be the required permissions for the attempted operation.

API call parameters from Make/Integromat module:

URL : https://api.linkedin.com/rest/shares

Headers : Content-Type application/json

Body :
{
"originalShare": "urn:li:share:1234567890",
"resharedShare": "urn:li:share:1234567890",
"text": {
"text": ""
},
"owner": "urn:li:organization:54321"
}

Method : POST

where urn:li:share:1234567890 is the existing brand page post I want to share and urn:li:organization:54321 is the brand page I want to share it on.

However, the API call consistently fails with the following error:
403: Not enough permissions to access: sharesV2.CREATE.20230401

This is despite my Make/Integromat scenario having an authorised connection to LinkedIn with the following permissions for all my organisation and brand pages:
r_liteprofile
rw_organization_admin
w_organization_social
r_organization_social
w_member_social

As I understand it, w_organization_social should be sufficient to share brand page posts?

Creation of the authorised connection is carried out via the Make/Integromat app.

The same authorised LinkedIn connection works fine with calls to other LinkedIn API endpoints
eg /rest/organizations

Answer (score 0):

you are using a deprecated endpoint. LinkedIn may have stopped supporting it. Why don't you try using the new endpoint instead?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin#creating-a-share-on-linkedin